# Mediatek GPS periodic mode

Tags: gps, sleep

I'm trying to build a low power GPS datalogger and I am trying to get the Mediatek based GPS module (Quectel L80-R) to run in periodic mode. I've sent the PMTK225 code to the module with various parameters, but it never seems to go into stand by or back up mode. Code below.

```
//Testing that commands sent to the GPS unit work

#include <NeoSWSerial.h>
NeoSWSerial gpsPort(3,2); // pins 3/2

#include <NMEAGPS.h>
NMEAGPS gps;

void setup() {

  // connect at 115200 so we can read the GPS fast enough and echo without   dropping chars
  // also spit it out
  Serial.begin(115200);

  gpsPort.begin( 9600 );
  gps.send_P( &gpsPort, F("PMTK605")); //firmware version
  delay(100);
  //gps.send_P( &gpsPort, F("PMTK314,-1")); //reset to default
  //gps.send_P( &gpsPort, F("PMTK314,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0") ); // RMC_GGA
  //gps.send_P( &gpsPort, F("PMTK314,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0") ); // RMC only
  delay( 100 );
  //gps.send_P( &gpsPort, F("PMTK220,200") );  // 5Hz
  //gps.send_P( &gpsPort, F("PMTK220,1000") ); //1hz
  delay( 100 );
  //gps.send_P( &gpsPort, F("PMTK225,0")); // normal mode
  //gps.send_P( &gpsPort, F("PMTK223,1,25,180000,60000")); // ephemeris data receiving
  gps.send_P( &gpsPort, F("PMTK225,2,3000,10000")); //period mode but not working
  //gps.send_P( &gpsPort, F("PMTK161")); //stand by mode
  //gps.send_P( &gpsPort, F("PMTK103")); //cold start
  delay(100);
  gps.send_P( &gpsPort, F("PMTK314,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0") ); // RMC only

  //gps.send_P( &gpsPort, F("PGCMD,33,0") );   // No antenna status messages needed
  delay( 100 );

  Serial.println("Ready!");
}


void loop() {
  if (gpsPort.available())
    Serial.write( gpsPort.read() );
}
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Why will it not go into periodic standby with the code above?

Answer (score 1):

Quectel L80-R does NOT have periodic mode, while the L80 does.